# SAP HANA - Trigger Insert into new table when old table has an insert

Tags: sql, triggers, insert, hana

I'm trying to create a trigger that will insert all new entries from `table_A` into `table_B` under another schema (Exact definition for both tables).

`Table_A` receives thousands of inserts every time, so the trigger should insert only new inserted rows data, and don't include old ones every time.

Found couple of solution for SQL SERVER, none of it works for SAP HANA.

Thank you.

Comment: What is a "new" entry to you in this scenario? If the entry refers to a non-unique key that is already present in table_A? What have you tried so far (code!) that didn't work? What is the semantic for table_B? Should it always contain the latest "version" on entries or the first version or what? Which HANA version are you using?

Comment: Thank you for your time, ok let me explain. 
I have Table A (Name_1, Name_2, Note, Date), this table recieves thousands of inserts, first day of every month through a Python script.

I need all these new inserted data to be inserted on another table (Table B, same definition, on another server) as well.

Date always equals first day of every month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make 2 **Procedures** Proc1 takes insert for the old table and proc2 for the new table.
Call proc2 from proc1 with the new values in cursor. For getting the new entries make sure the table has a time stamp field (ex- CREATED_AT), store the last value inserted in a variable and then after update fetch using the variable and pass to proc2.

Let me know if you need code for the same

Comment: Thank you Ayush, the insert for the first table (Table A) is already done through a python script, can not be touched. i need to transfer those inserts to a second table (Table A), taking only new entries.

Comment: In this case get the last record from the Table(Table B) you want to insert in, using that last record ID(or any other unique field) query and get all new fields from existing table(Table A) and make a insert.